# Difference between getter and a regular method in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, getter-setter

I'm just getting my feet wet with the BLoC architecture of Flutter. Here, I wish to create a `Bloc` class, which will help me to convert the user input in the form of stream data. To do that task, let's say that first of all I create an instance of `Bloc` class with the name `email` and then,

1. make use of snippet 0 & then call `email.emailController.sink.add(some_string)`
2. or, make use of snippet 1 and then call `email.streamEmail(some_string)`
3. or, make use of snippet 2 code and then call `email.streamEmail(some_string)`

to add a string input to the stream

Code snippets:

```
//Snippet 0 : w/o any `method`
class Bloc{
 final emailController = StreamController<String>();
}
```

```
//Snippet 1 : using regular 'method'
class Bloc{
 final emailController = StreamController<String>();
 void streamEmail(String value) => emailController.sink.add(value);
}
```

```
//Snippet 2 : using 'get' based 'method'
class Bloc{
 final emailController = StreamController<String>();
 Function(String) get streamEmail => emailController.sink.add;
}
```

I learned that making use of snippet 1 or 2 is a rather better to approach, in terms of code readability.
I know that snippet 1& 2 are just 2 different ways of doing the same thing. However, I'm not clear about the differences that snippet 2 brings in, by making use of the getter method.

From [A tour of the Dart language](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters),

> Getters and setters are special methods that provide read and write access to an object’s properties.

At the moment, the only thing I understand about getters is that they represent an alternative approach to define methods within a class. So, to be precise my questions are :

1. Does usage of a getter method lead to enhancement or drop in-app. performance?
2. When & why should I be using snippet 2 type class definitions instead of snippet 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does usage of a getter method lead enhancement or drop in app. performance?

No, using getter/setter instead of methods does not impact performance.

> When & why should I be using snippet 2 type class definitions instead of snippet 1?

When to use getters/setters is a question about taste and some developers are more likely to use them than others. I guess a general design goal should be that getters/setters acts like normal properties on an object and should therefore not make any additional unknown behavior than getting/setting a property. (e.g. get a property of a objects will end up saving some files to the file system).

In your example I would go with snippet 1 (and maybe with a different name of the method) since your example is not really a good use case of using properties. Snippet 2 seems like a forced clever attempt to make use a getter which ends up being a little weird since the getter ends up returning a Function.

But again, this is a question about taste and I am sure there are some developers which would go with snippet 2.

Comment: Can you point me to the specific source of your answer? Or is it like, based on your experience with Dart?

Comment: There are some guidelines here for Dart: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-use-getters-for-operations-that-conceptually-access-properties . The guidelines I have learned from comes primary from this document for C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/bzwdh01d(v=vs.71)

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well as the sources.